# Type Conversions

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pytorch

I'm quite new to pytorch so I'm not exactly sure if this is a bug or just an error on my end.

I'm attempting to build a simple LogisticRegression Module on the `make_classification` dataset in sklearn but for some reason, I keep getting this.

> RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2'

I've tried to convert the both my X and y variables to `double` but it still seems to think it's float for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=60000,n_features=10, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2)

X_train,y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)

X_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X_train)).double()
y_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train)).double()
X_test = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X_test)).double()
y_test = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_test)).double()
```

Here's the network

```
input_dim = 40000
output_dim = 2
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 100
n_iters = 3000
num_epochs = int(n_iters / (len(X_train) / batch_size))

model = SingleLayeredNetwork(input_dim, output_dim)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

class SingleLayeredNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dimension, output_dimension):
        super(SingleLayeredNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(input_dimension, output_dimension)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        return out
```

Here's the training loop

```
iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
for train, test in zip(X_train, y_train):
    train = train.double()
    print(train)
    print(train.dtype)
    print(torch.typename(train))
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs = model(train)
    loss = criterion(outputs, test)

    loss.backward()

    # Updating parameters
    optimizer.step()

    iter += 1

    if iter % 500 == 0:
        # Calculate Accuracy         
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        # Iterate through test dataset
        for tra, tes in zip(X_test, y_test):
            # Load images to a Torch Variable
            tra = tra

            # Forward pass only to get logits/output
            outputs = model(tra)

            # Get predictions from the maximum value
            # 100 x 1
            _, predicted = torch.max(train, 1)

            # Total number of labels
            total += labels.size(0)

            # Total correct predictions
            correct += (predicted == test).sum()

        accuracy = 100 * correct.item() / total

        # Print Loss
        print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss.item(), accuracy))
```

Here's the error I keep getting

---

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        10         optimizer.zero_grad()
>        11 
>   ---> 12         outputs = model(train)
>        13         loss = criterion(outputs, test)
>        14
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
>   in **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       488         else:
>   --> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> in forward(self, x)
>         5 
>         6     def forward(self, x):
>   ----> 7         out = self.layer(x)
>         8         return out
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
>   in **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       488         else:
>   --> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py
>   in forward(self, input)
>        65     @weak_script_method
>        66     def forward(self, input):
>   ---> 67         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
>        68 
>        69     def extra_repr(self):
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py
>   in linear(input, weight, bias)    1352         ret =
>   torch.addmm(torch.jit._unwrap_optional(bias), input, weight.t())
>   1353     else:
>   -> 1354         output = input.matmul(weight.t())    1355         if bias is not None:    1356             output +=
>   torch.jit._unwrap_optional(bias)
>
> RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar
>   type Float for argument #2 'mat2'

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem is a mismatch between the data (which you're making double) and your model (which will default to float). I'd suggest converting your data to float i.e. by replacing your calls to `double` with `float`.